# How to set a dynamic end cell while using an ActiveCell.Offset for the Start Cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a table to pull information from separate work books.currently the table has a set end cell, but I'm pulling into too much information. I want to set the end cell to the last row of the data in column D. I need help modifying the code to set the end cell to a dynamic range.

I've already tried to use `lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row` but I keep getting

> compile error

at the preceding `.Offset` that is invalid or unqualified reference

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim strWhereToCopy As String, strStartCellColName As String
    Dim strListSheet As String
    Dim strCopySheet As String

    strListSheet = "List"

    On Error GoTo ErrH
    Sheets(strListSheet).Select
    Range("B2").Select

'this is the main loop, we will open the files one by one and copy their data into the masterdata sheet
    Set currentWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

        strFileName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & ActiveCell.Value
        strCopyRange = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) & ":" & lastRow = 
.Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
        strWhereToCopy = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
        strCopySheet = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
        strStartCellColName = Mid(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5), 2, 1)

        Application.Workbooks.Open strFileName, UpdateLinks:=False, 
ReadOnly:=True
        Set dataWB = ActiveWorkbook

        Sheets(strCopySheet).Select
        Range(strCopyRange).Select
        Selection.Copy

        currentWB.Activate
        Sheets(strWhereToCopy).Select
        lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn(strStartCellColName)
        Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select

        Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        dataWB.Close False
        Sheets(strListSheet).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    Exit Sub

ErrH:
    MsgBox "It seems some file was missing. The data copy operation is not 
complete."
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Please read up on how to [avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: I Agree with SJR, you should avoid using the select. In regards to you defining 'lastrow.' I don't see too much in the way there, but again I would work select